# iOS Design: TableViews or Other?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm currently at a stage within my app design phase where I am totally stuck as to which method would be more suitable, `tableView` or something else?

My app currently pulls large data sets into a `CoreData` model, some of these objects have objects related to them.

I wish to display a list of the topmost level object (easy enough, just bang it into a dynamic `tableView`). However, this is where my problem lies, when I click an object in this first `tableView`, I want another `tableView` to appear to it's side with a list of all it's related objector "children". Then I want the same to happen on these children objects once clicked.

I have attached a screen cap of how I wish it to look once a new `tableView` is created, this is currently created on viewLoad, which is incorrect for my specification as it loads all the children of all the objects:

[image: Sensitive Info Censored, target layout]

Would this be best achieved using multiple `tableView` in the same `storyBoard`, or is there another method I am overlooking which would be more suitable?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you create a horizontal collection view, with a custom cell that has a table? and whenever the desired action is performed you can simply add one more cell to the collection view (which will be a table view itself).

Comment: Use UISplitViewController as it is container view controller that implements a master-detail interface. in your case first tableview will be in the masterviewcontroller and on tap of the cell detailviewcontroller will be populated with detail data.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest, and most "Apple" way would be to push to a new `UITableViewController` when a cell is tapped on. In the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function, you could use the `indexPath.row` value to retrieve the object and then pass this through to the next ViewController for rendering within another `UITableView`.

As you have mentioned that you may be handling a lot of child data, the way to handle this would be to create a generic subclass of UITableViewController, we'll call it `GenericTableViewController`, with a property named `dataArray` to hold your child data. In the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` function, instantiate a `GenericTableViewController`, assign the selected object's children to `dataArray` and push the new `GenericTableViewController` onto the navigation stack. This will allow you to repeat this for as long as you may need, depending on how many child objects you have.

Your `UIStoryBoard` would consist of one `UITableViewController` embedded within a `UINavigationController`. This `UITableViewController` would handle the presentation of the `GenericTableViewController`. Then in turn, each `GenericTableViewController` would handle the presentation of another `GenericTableViewController`.

Comment: This is very helpful, many thanks for the well detailed answer!

Comment: @LewisSeddon No problem! Hope this helps!